# Nodejs API call returning undefined to lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This is the aws lambda function which will invoke an api:

```
'use strict';

var request = require("request")

exports.handler = function (event, context,callback) {



let url = "https://3sawt0jvzf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/test"

request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: event,

}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        callback(null, { "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
                          "statusCode": "200",
                          "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue"},
                          "body": body});
    }
    else {

        console.log("error: " + error)
        console.log("response.statusCode: " + response.statusCode)
        console.log("response.statusText: " + response.statusText)
    }
})
};
```

This is the api written as an aws lambda function:

```
'use strict';


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
console.log(event.name);
callback(null, { "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
                 "statusCode": "200",
                 "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue"},
                 "body": `Hello World ${event.name}`});  // SUCCESS with message
};
```

When I try to call the api from the lambda function it just returns "Hello World undefined". It is not appending the name at the end and returning the correct response.

Comment: console.log(event.name); is this logging even.name properly?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan  yes

Comment: `console.log(event.name)` works but not `${event.name}`? Something's not right.

Comment: Then defenitely something wrong with template string. To prove that can you please try old way of appending string, 'Hello World ' + event.name

Comment: Added an answer. I belive your node version is below v4.0.0

Comment: Both of the above console.log statements are working fine.What I meant was this: JSON.parse(event) is nit helping me since it shows an error which means it is already an object. When I am testing the api in lambda console then it is giving correct response but while invoking it from browser or another lambda function it is showing Hello world undefined.

Comment: I have made an edit in the json that is being passed

Comment: excellent. May I know what the edit was if you don't mind. Just curios to know the issue :)

Comment: it's still not working....it was just to inform you guys about the edit: request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: event,

}

Comment: Don't test it using Lambda console. It confuses us. Test by sending an HTTP request to it and tell us what's in `console.log(event)`.

Comment: I am sending request  using postman and all it outputs is "hello undefined". I am unable to see any output of the console.log statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Assumptions:*

- You're using Lambda-Proxy Integration.
- You want to pass the the exact same payload that the first Lambda received to the second Lambda.*

You're misunderstanding what `event` is. This is NOT the JSON payload that you sent through your HTTP request.

An HTTP request through the API Gateway gets transformed into an `event` object similar to this:

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {Incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```

As you can see, the JSON payload is accessible in a stringified form in `event.body`.

If you want to send the pass the same payload to the second Lambda, you have to parse it first.

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
```

Then, send `body` instead of `event`.

Then, in your second Lambda, you parse the stringified JSON in `event.body` and then you get your original payload back.

If you sent `name` in that original payload, you can get it from `JSON.parse(event.body).name`.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format

Comment: Both of the above console.log statements are working fine.What I meant was this: JSON.parse(event) is nit helping me since it shows an error which means it is already an object. When I am testing the api in lambda console then it is giving correct response but while invoking it from browser or another lambda function it is showing Hello world undefined.

Comment: I have made an edit in the json that is being passed

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem and debugged with logging event to console.

Add logging on the event,

> console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

to evaluate how mapping is done in your API-Gateway to Lambda integration and see where the post parameter exists.

If the post value is not there fix the integration until you get the post values in your event.

**Data Mapping API-Gateway to Lambda:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Both of the above console.log statements are working fine.What I meant was this: JSON.parse(event) is nit helping me since it shows an error which means it is already an object. When I am testing the api in lambda console then it is giving correct response but while invoking it from browser or another lambda function it is showing Hello world undefined.

Comment: Try logging event and attach response to question

Comment: while testing, my input(i.e event) is this { "name" :"basant"} and this is the same output while giving console.log. But when I try to invoke this api from another lambda function or  from the browser it says Hello world undefined.The name is not being passed for some reason

Comment: I have made an edit in the json that is being passed

Comment: Copy and paste the line which I highlighted and call from your lambda, not through testing and paste the response

Answer (score 1):

I had some very similar problem. When trying to call `JSON.parse()` on the `event.body`, I'm getting an error because event is already the object that I'm trying to `POST`. I haven't actually linked my database to my front end, but I have this error while testing from Lambda and from API Gateway.

Example of how I'm being able only now to read the object from my request:

```
"use strict";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let responseBody; 
let statusCode;

console.log(event.id) // I have access to dot notation straight from the event

const {id, item, quantity, orderTotal, userId} = event;
```